# form.radio button in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, radio-button

How to select and create radio button in rails 3 when using like this 
Database records like this

id name selected 
1 abc false
2 efg true
3 hij false
4 klm false

The above will display on form as four radio buttons 
I am using form_for and need to use f.radio_button for each group...

How to achieve which one is selected

thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
      Fetch all the records from database in @records then in your view file

      <% @records.each do |row| %>
        <br><%= radio_button_tag 'field_name', row.name, row.selected %>
        <%= row.name.humanize %>
      <% end %>
```

Comment: hi, but how can we send selected value ? . i am using form_for for this scenario.

Comment: You don't need to anything. After form submit you will get the required value in params[:field_name]. You can use form for also

Comment: but i was having the same radio buttons based on groups , means one form will have more groups with radio buttons . can we achieve this for my scenario. thanks